# Client for performing ElasticSearch requests

Tags: web-apps, database, database-browser

I make a lot of use of an ElasticSearch server, and up until now have been using Sense. However, this has recently disappeared from the Chrome Store, and our IT department's virus scanner has disabled the Chrome plugin.

In the meantime I've been using Postman, which works, but is a little less ergonomic than Sense was, being more generic.

It's an old version of Elastic Search (1.4.4) and there are no clever plugins installed. I don't have control over what is installed on the ElasticSearch server either.

What are my options? Autocomplete to help me write the queries would be very useful.

Something that runs inside a Linux virtual machine would be best, as I do most of my development work there, and don't have much control over the Windows machine that hosts my Linux VM.

Answer (score 0):

[kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) may be the tool to look at, it has a good few visulization features, but also a console to help with development.

Answer (score 0):

I like the console in Kibana. All text in it is saved. Kibana is a good research tool. The Discover tab gives you all the power of Lucene and you can add filters using the Elasticsearch DSL.

Even if you don't need the visualizations, it's a powerful front end for Elasticsearch.